# Simple grid for simple games

Tags: beginner, c, game

As my first project in C (and also final project for [CS50](https://cs50.harvard.edu/)) I made a Tetris clone using the library `ncurses`.

This is the grid I wrote for the game. I guess it could be easily reused for similar projects since I tried to make it "not Tetris specific".

`grid.h`

```
#ifndef GRID_HEADER
#define GRID_HEADER

#include "colors.h"
#include "helpers.h"

#define EMPTY_CONTENT 0

/*
 * grid_block:  represents a grid block.
 *
 * content: content of the block. If equal to EMPTY_CONTENT, the block is
 *          considered empty.
 * color  : color of the content.
 */
typedef struct
{
        char content;
        colors color;
} grid_block;

/*
 * grid:  represents a grid.
 *
 * blocks: a "dynamic multidimensional array" storing rows x cols blocks.
 * rows  : number of rows of the grid.
 * cols  : number of columns of the grid.
 */
typedef struct
{
        grid_block *blocks;
        int rows;
        int cols;
} grid;

/*
 * create_grid:  creates and return (a pointer to) a new empty grid of size
 *               rows x cols.
 */
grid *create_grid(int rows, int cols);

/*
 * is_valid_position:  return true if row, col is a valid position on the grid
 *                     grid.
 */
bool is_valid_position(const grid *grid, int row, int col);

/*
 * is_empty_position:  return true if the block at position row, col is empty.
 */
bool is_empty_position(const grid *grid, int row, int col);

/*
 * is_full_row:  return true if every block in row is not empty.
 */
bool is_full_row(const grid *grid, int row);

/* 
 * get_block:  return a copy of the block at position row, col.
 */
grid_block get_block(const grid *grid, int row, int col);

/*
 * fill_block:  puts content and color in the block at position row, col.
 */
void fill_block(grid *grid, char content, colors color, int row, int col);

/*
 * flush_block:  makes block at position row, col an empty block.
 */
void flush_block(grid *grid, int row, int col);

/*
 * flush_row:  makes all blocks in row empty blocks.
 */
void flush_row(grid *grid, int row);

/*
 * flush_grid:  makes all blocks in the grid grid empty blocks.
 */
void flush_grid(grid *grid);

/*
 * swap_rows:  swaps the blocks in row1 with the blocks in row2.
 */
void swap_rows(grid *grid, int row1, int row2);

/*
 * free_grid:  frees all memory occupied by grid.
 */
void free_grid(grid *grid);

#endif
```

`colors.h`

```
#ifndef COLORS_HEADER
#define COLORS_HEADER

#include <ncurses.h>

typedef enum
{
        BLACK   = COLOR_BLACK,
        RED     = COLOR_RED,
        GREEN   = COLOR_GREEN,
        YELLOW  = COLOR_YELLOW,
        BLUE    = COLOR_BLUE,
        MAGENTA = COLOR_MAGENTA,
        CYAN    = COLOR_CYAN,
        WHITE   = COLOR_WHITE
} colors;

#endif
```

`helpers` contains helpers functions for the entire program. Here the only one used by `grid`: a `malloc` wrapper.

`helpers.h`

```
#ifndef HELPERS_HEADER
#define HELPERS_HEADER

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/*
 * safe_malloc:  allocates size bytes and returns a void pointer to the
 *               allocated memory. On failure, prints an error end calls
 *               exit(EXIT_FAILURE).
 */
void *safe_malloc(size_t size);

#endif
```

`helpers.c`

```
#include "helpers.h"


void *safe_malloc(size_t size)
{
        void *ptr = malloc(size);

        if (ptr == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "error: cannot allocate %zu bytes of memory\n",
                        size);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return ptr;
}
```

`grid.c`

```
#include "grid.h"


grid *create_grid(int rows, int cols)
{
        grid *new_grid = safe_malloc(sizeof(*new_grid));
        grid_block *new_blocks = safe_malloc(sizeof(*new_blocks) * rows * cols);

        new_grid->blocks = new_blocks;
        new_grid->rows = rows;
        new_grid->cols = cols;

        flush_grid(new_grid);

        return new_grid;
}

bool is_valid_position(const grid *grid, int row, int col)
{
        return (row >= 0 && row < grid->rows) && (col >= 0 && col < grid->cols);
}

bool is_empty_position(const grid *grid, int row, int col)
{
        return get_block(grid, row, col).content == EMPTY_CONTENT;
}

bool is_full_row(const grid *grid, int row)
{
        for (int col = 0; col < grid->cols; col++) {
                if (is_empty_position(grid, row, col)) {
                        return false;
                }
        }
        return true;
}

grid_block get_block(const grid *grid, int row, int col)
{
        return grid->blocks[row * grid->cols + col];
}

void fill_block(grid *grid, char content, colors color, int row, int col)
{
        grid->blocks[row * grid->cols + col].content = content;
        grid->blocks[row * grid->cols + col].color = color;
}

void flush_block(grid *grid, int row, int col)
{
        grid->blocks[row * grid->cols + col].content = EMPTY_CONTENT;
}

void flush_row(grid *grid, int row)
{
        for (int col = 0; col < grid->cols; col++) {
                flush_block(grid, row, col);
        }
}

void flush_grid(grid *grid)
{
        for (int row = 0; row < grid->rows; row++) {
                flush_row(grid, row);
        }
}

void swap_rows(grid *grid, int row1, int row2)
{
        grid_block temp1;
        grid_block temp2;

        for (int col = 0; col < grid->cols; col++) {

                temp1 = get_block(grid, row1, col);
                temp2 = get_block(grid, row2, col);

                fill_block(grid, temp1.content, temp1.color, row2, col);
                fill_block(grid, temp2.content, temp2.color, row1, col);
        }
}

void free_grid(grid *grid)
{
        free(grid->blocks);
        free(grid);
}
```

I'd like to get some feedback. My main concerns are:

- Is the use of a `malloc` wrapper a "good practice"? Basically I used it every time I needed memory in the program.
- Calling functions inside other functions (e.g. like `flush_grid()` who calls `flush_row()` on each row which in turn calls `flush_block()` on each block) could add a significant overhead? Because in this way, it looks really "clean" to me, but I'd like to hear others people thoughts.
- Last but not least: my usage of `const` in the functions declarations. I used it more like a way of saying "hey look: this function will leave the grid in its current state" or "hey look: this function will modify one or more block in the grid changing its state".
  For example, I could declare `flush_block()` in this way `void flush_block(const grid *grid, int row, int col);` since `grid->blocks`, `grid->rows` and `grid->cols` will remain the same, but I thought would be more "useful" the approach I used. What do you think? (Hope I have explained my point well).

Link to the full [Tetris clone](https://github.com/MarcoLucidi01/tetris_clone) for the curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use of a `malloc` wrapper

Code is reasonable.  The larger issue is how to handle errors.  Detect them is one thing, but them what?  At least the code sends a message and quits.

The function can fail a corner case: `size == 0`.  Returning `NULL` in that case is not an out-of-memory.

```
   void *ptr = malloc(size);
   // if (ptr == NULL) {
   if (ptr == NULL && size > 0) {
     error_code();
   }
```

For completeness, I'd recommend `safe_realloc(), safe_calloc()` and  `safe_free()` (even if it is only a simple wrapper).  Code's "safe-ness" may evolve.

2. functions inside other functions

Yes there is a function calling a function calling a function, etc. that could have been handled with one function and perform a *little* bit faster.  Yet unless this is a real performance concern, write for clarity and maintainability.  Optimization efforts are best spent reducing the order of complexity `O()` of a task and not simple linear performance gains.  Code is fine.

3. usage of `const`

Code's usage is good and correct.  This correct usage can allow some compilers to further optimize code as well provide the self-documentation OP noted.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think to that corner case, I'm going to fix it!